# List Break Inheritance, Copy Parent Roles, Delete a Particular Group

Tags: permissions, groups

I want to delete a particular Group of permissions after breaking inheritance on List and copying parent roles down.

The code i have is, which is working, my question is is this the correct method to be using?  i.e `oList.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(group).deleteObject();`

Thank You

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

    oList.breakRoleInheritance(true);

    var group = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName(groupName);

    oList.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(group).deleteObject();

    clientContext.load(group);
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        deferred.resolve(group);
    },
         function (sender, args) {
             deferred.reject(args.get_message());
         });

    return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what you are doing is correct.

You can view the official documentation on [How to: Break Role Assignment Inheritance Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

The subsection on [Breaking the Security Inheritance of a Document and Changing the Permissions of a User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013%28v=office.14%29.aspx#sectionSection2) is the most pertinent.

Comment: Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Comment: this might be slightly different question, is it possible to search on all list groups permissions levels, i.e if i have two groups with have Edit permissions, can i return the name property of these 2 groups?

    `demoList.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)` always returns true even if the list has no groups added.

Comment: check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935101/get-user-group-permissions-for-list-using-javascriptecmascript